Can we find a better tag for this?
I don't really like the tag "marketing" for the question
What is a good way to concisely explain Bitcoin?
It sounds to much like this is a strategy-to-promote-bitcoin site instead of the factual Q and A that it is.  But I wasn't immediately able to find any more appropriate tags for it.  Anyone else have ideas?
Clearly this question and others like it need categorisation.  But without resorting to meta-tags, what categorisation is appropriate?

How about a plain and simple introduction?

elevator-pitch 
The term is usual for introductory explanations that take less than 2 minutes. Read more here: Elevator Pitch

evangelism, promotion?

Even worse!  This is supposed to be a factual reference, and the question/answer are clearly on topic.  We should be able to give it a legitimate tag.  I realise the fact that it literally covers all of Bitcoin makes it somewhat general, but still.
